# Can I set a variable with the result of "match"?

Tags: python

Setting a variable with a `match` can be done simply like this:

```py
Mode = 'fast'
puts = ''
match Mode:
    case "slow":
        puts = 'v2 k5'
    case "balanced":
        puts = 'v3 k5'
    case "fast":
        puts = 'v3 k7'
```

But can you do something like this?

```py
Mode = 'fast'
puts = match Mode:
    case "slow": 'v2 k5'
    case "balanced": 'v3 k5'
    case "fast": 'v3 k7'
```

Currently it results in a syntax error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not as far as I know in python.  In this case I wouldn't use pattern matching at all:

```py
puts = {
    "slow": "v2 k5",
    "balanced": "v3 k5",
    "fast": "v3 k7"
}.get(Mode, default)
```

Clearer, more declarative, and no repeating yourself.  But of course you can't use clever pattern destructuring.

Answer (score 7):

`match` is a statement, not an expression, so it can't be used on the right-hand side of an assignment.

The reasoning is outlined in PEP 622: https://peps.python.org/pep-0622/#make-it-an-expression, and also in PEP 635: https://peps.python.org/pep-0635/#the-match-statement (*Statement vs. Expression*)